# Export Line Feature using ogr2ogr.

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, oracle-spatial

I am trying to export a line feature class from an oracle spatial database to a file geodatabase.  I can export polygons with no problem, but cannot find the appropriate command '-nlt' for Line Feature.

```
    ogr2ogr  -update -overwrite -nln  CONVERT_TO_LINEAR  -nln sf_line -a_srs EPSG:3089 -progress -f FileGDB g:/...." "
```

Comment: Where have you searched? Ogr2ogr manual http://www.gdal.org/ogr2ogr.html is listing `Define the geometry type for the created layer. One of NONE, GEOMETRY, POINT, LINESTRING, POLYGON, GEOMETRYCOLLECTION, MULTIPOINT, MULTIPOLYGON or MULTILINESTRING. And CIRCULARSTRING, COMPOUNDCURVE, CURVEPOLYGON, MULTICURVE and MULTISURFACE for GDAL 2.0 non-linear geometry types`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I have been using this manual, and have attempted GEOMETRY, GEOMETRYCOLLECTIOn, and some others but to no avail.  Polygon works, but it converts the lines to polygons and closes those shapes.  Linestring converts to exports out a table only.

Comment: I think it is very unlikely that with your command ogr2ogr is taking lines and closing them into polygons. I rather believe that what you have in Oracle are polygons.

Comment: What do you get with this SQL `select distinct a.geom.sdo_gtype from your_table a;`? Naturally you must edit the SQL a bit to suit your table.

Comment: Your question is definitely not clear. You say polygons export successfully, but lines don't ? Or is it that you want to export lines as polygons ? Or maybe polygons are lines ? Why do you have two -nln parameters in your command.

Comment: user30184, I cannot get the sql for a distinct sdo_gtype to work.  Here is a sample output: MDSYS.SDO_GEOMETRY(2002,1003089,NULL,MDSYS.SDO_ELEM_INFO_ARRAY(1,2,1),MDSYS.SDO_ORDINATE_ARRAY . . . It is my understanding that the '2' from the 2002 would indicate a line.  I got that info from: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14255/sdo_objrelschema.htm

Comment: Albert Godfrind - I am trying to export a line as a line.  I was just saying that in other instances when I export shapes, I have not problem exporting points or polygons.

Comment: Albert Godfrind - the two 'nln's are a typo.  That should be 'nlt'.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to use the '-nlt linestring' to export a line feature class successfully.  The error appears to have been embedded in the sql statement.  I was joining two tables and a view.  The view was originally written using the 'myview.*'.  I changed the SQL so that added each variable individually. This seemed to work.

```
    table1.var1, table2.var2, myview.variable1, myview.variable2 . . . myview.variableN'.
```